# Skewness and kurtosis measures when full distribution is not available

Tags: risk, distribution, skewness, kurtosis

I have asked this question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/442027/skewness-and-kurtosis-using-quantiles-and-mean-variance), but did not get any answer. I was wondering if anybody knows a method of deriving skewness and kurtosis measures from different quantiles, mean, and/or variance. I do not have access to the full distribution of returns, but can get any quantile, along with mean and variance.

Thanks and let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Maybe this can help a little: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432439/relation-of-variance-and-skewness-for-a-skewed-gaussian-variable